# existence of a local minimum of a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

I know that if a function $f$ is continuous on a compact domain then the global minimum and maximum exist. But what if $f$ is differentiable, $f \ge 0$, and its domain is unbounded. Is a local minimum of $f$ guaranteed to exist? Are there examples of functions which satisfy the aforementioned conditions for which a local minimum does not exist (thereby the gradient at that point is not 0)?

Comment: $f(x) = e^x$ ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hmm, that is true! But, in this case, $f'(x) = e^x$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f'(x) = 0$. I know that the derivative is never 0 and I know that this has no local minimum but is there an example for which $f'(x)$ is 'sufficiently' far from 0? I'm just curious how prevalent these functions are or if they are 'rare'

Comment: $g(x) = \arctan(x) + \pi$

Comment: Concerning your follow-up question: if there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ for which $f'(x) > \epsilon$ for all $x$, then this function cannot satisfy $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$.  Sketch of proof:  given $a < b$, $f'(x) > \epsilon$ implies that $f(b) - f(a) > \epsilon(b-a)$.  If $b = 0$, we must have $f(a) < f(0) + \epsilon a$ for all $a < 0$.  For sufficiently negative $a$, the RHS of this last inequality will be negative.

Comment: (Similar arguments can be used in the case where $f'(x) < \epsilon < 0$)